# Calls to WCF Service occasionally hang

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, odata

The issue was originally encountered on a WCF Data Service (OData) where a large amount of data was being returned (~3MB) and the application consuming the data (an MVC website) would sporadically hang on some of the requests and would eventually time out.

The issue could be replicated on smaller data payloads but would take a long time to occur. The issue has been replicated on both Cassini and IIS 7. When running through IIS I could see the hung W3 worker process stuck in the 'SendResponse' state until it times out.

To narrow down the cause of the issue I created a console app that would sequentially download content from an ASP.NET site. The issue was replicated on a WCF Data Service (OData), a standard WCF Service, and a Web Forms page that output similar data directly to the HttpResponse object. The example code used is using the standard WCF Service as an example (for ease of setup for those trying to replicate it).

Console App Client:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.ReadKey(); // press any key to start test

        do
        {
            var req = WebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://localhost:26332/WCFTest.svc/GetData"));
            var response = req.GetResponse();

            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                var content = new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();           
            }           
        } while (true);
    }
```

WCF Service:

```
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public TestClass[] GetData()
        {
            return Enumerable
                .Range(0, 15000)
                .Select(i => new TestClass{ ID = "1" })
                .ToArray();
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class TestClass
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string ID { get; set; }
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetData")]
        TestClass[] GetData();
    }
```

After a number of calls (this differs on each run, but is usually less than 30) to the web service the GetResponseStream call will hang.

Any ideas on what could be going wrong or how to narrow down the cause of the issue would be appreciated!

Service web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService2.Service1" >
        <endpoint
          address=""
          binding="webHttpBinding"
          contract="WcfService2.IService1"
          behaviorConfiguration="webHttp"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttp">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

WCF Data Services code:

```
public class Service1 : DataService<ODataContext>
{
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration configuration)
    {
        configuration.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
    }
}

public class ODataContext
{
    public IQueryable<TestClass> Test
    {
        get
        {
            return Enumerable
                .Range(0, 15000)
                .Select(i => new TestClass {ID = "1"})
                .AsQueryable();
        }
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Added the WCF Service web.config as requested. The only addition to the standard web.config is a webHttp behaviour.

Comment: I will try to repro on WCF Data Services if you have that code available; probably looks pretty similar to the above. On a side note, what version of WCF Data Services did you try on? (Not that I expect that to make a difference, based on your description of the problem.)

Comment: @MarkStafford-MSFT I tried it on Version 5.0.1 of WCF Data Services Server. I've updated the question to include the code.

Comment: Hmmm... I made trivial modifications (namespace, etc) and ran it in a loop from a console app - no hangs in over a thousand iterations. I didn't modify my Web.config at all. Could it be environmental? Network? Host? I'm playing just on my local box with Win8/VS2012/IISExpress.

Comment: @MarkStafford-MSFT Looks like the the corporate anti-virus was to blame. Appreciate you taking the time to try to replicate the issue, and sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: I'm just glad to hear that it wasn't systemic to our stack. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was an issue with ESET anti-virus inspecting incoming HTTP traffic and dropping some packets. Uninstalling ESET resolved the issue.

For further information on the ESET issue: http://www.wilderssecurity.com/showthread.php?t=332920